# Apex Clone trying to write to a non writeable field on the Asset Object

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method, asset

First time posting and pretty new to writing APEX (thanks ChatGPT).

In Sandbox, I have written an invocable class, based on a collection of assets being passed in too clone and a certain number of variables passed in to modify both the original and cloned assets. In Sandbox it works exactly as I want it too no errors.

Once deployed to production though, I get this error

**Error Occurred: A field wasn't found or isn't supported for Apex action InvocableAssetCloning: Asset.Address**

Address on Asset is **not a writeable field**, it's not in my code anywhere and even if it is cloned it's a constructed field.
In the schema, the asset object doesn't even have the breakdown of address fields, e.g billing country etc.
We don't even use the address field, but I added to a layout to check and it is the country field that has a value.

I just want to ignore it, not update it with null or anything like that. Just don't do anything apex.

Can anyone help with this? Chapt GPT wasn't very helpful.